# Show raise to power in static text Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm making a GUI in MATLAB. I want to know how to show/represent raise to power in static text in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `^` character.  MATLAB implemented basic TeX style formatting several years ago into text boxes, so `_` is interpreted as subscript.  If you actually want these symbols to appear in your text, place a `\` then place your symbol after it (i.e. `\_` or `\^`).

Comment: It prints that character but I want to know that is there any method for which ^ character not show instead any number would show as power? As in **cos ^ -1** -1 would show as power.

Comment: What kind of static text are you trying to produce? A text **label**?

Comment: If I am interpreting what you are saying properly, all labels should still follow the same guideline.  Basic TeX syntax has been accepted so that you can format labels with some basic mathematical notation.  You're either not using the right widget or you are using a widget that clearly doesn't support what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks man for helping me. You really help me lot. Others problems are also solved.